# Issue sending email from localhost using amazon web services SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am trying to use AWS SES in order to send a few emails from localhost for testing purposes.

I recently changed my SMTP credentials on the AWS console and whenever I try and send emails from my local app using SES, the emails do not reach the recipient and bounce back to the sender with the following headers:

```
From MAILER-DAEMON@us-west-2.amazonses.com Sun May 29 14:58:50 2016
X-Apparently-To: balteo@yahoo.fr; Sun, 29 May 2016 14:58:53 +0000
Return-Path: <>
Received-SPF: none (domain of a27-7.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com does not designate permitted sender hosts)
 ZXIgdGhlIG1haWwgdG8gdGhlIGZvbGxvd2luZyByZWNpcGllbnRzOiBiYWx0
 ZW9AZ21haWwuY29tIFJlcG9ydGluZy1NVEE6IGRzbjsgaHR0cDovL2EyNy0y
 MC5zbXRwLW91dC51cy13ZXN0LTIuYW1hem9uc2VzLmNvbSBBY3Rpb246IGZh
 aWxlZCBGaW5hbC1SZWNpcGllbnQ6IHJmYzgyMjsgYmFsdGVvQGdtYWlsLmNv
 bSBEaWFnbm9zdGljLUNvZGU6IHNtdHA7IDU1MC01LjcuMSBVbgEwAQEBAQN0
 ZXh0L3BsYWluAwMxAgNtZXNzYWdl5LXN0YXR1cwMDMQIDbWVz
 c2FnZS9yZmM4MjIDAzE-
X-YMailISG: 4snxmygWLDtHybe5o15zjCZDapQTVTu4hZDcv_TW4FCtWjE7
 nDyLE5rrMvq22rKmMVRtIU9m25fmKVqaIORTzaOy5PrNe8MDQhBIuhQrw6pR
 dBt2Pb9jHgAmt15fpNr_6_93fWOLc.GblGJ0Kv5eRJAfQPZ3I.x1IQrHzM2U
 KzhOd4LZdemwRNxyJ21xVmSVKXGdakQuJET3HOeIe.zZhfISk.d8yd.sCwYB
 klU0MnNCiSh_HkXzVyOA_Yjr.DqRxR4W_LwEdE3PaFjL9cGxpxfQ1mPX5UkG
 o9lVuHOkkjuXyhneDhztSnbNpe_1MDuqf8pNaG9eP.n.jRDX2hfMHGBXKekR
 VtS_0qY125Hpu0ULpS2ue4tZMyDZC4nhi9aKL5_LKKyMVgRaJhZIYDw.DyyO
 WgccC4BYS0AfIixDkTQHQLz9zRVVmkxYWWp7moTcCoGY.wxmK0rdFzoQmccn
 1ldvx1S_f3Nr6UwZmQ.WyOHwAINKw4bA3b94UebIkr7WYWFJStRu0ZpnUr.x
 gvfn7FGw4ywJ99qgLFbm8rasVkhvI2dQkCCSSvSQr67S_dd7g2k8xIixZ7qz
 IR7XZxt.AUBe1gHe9nuzdci6S2gAbhjdHJyyq6WXQghrZdsBUY_Yba5oZ81f
 1G0_SwvDRgw4DQ44EtCC.qcNEqiGdzjDQkowSSs1pTx3B_o.81PdjNdJshVR
 b5KDfdjSYBqAFs6QEj9kpfpAMtmK9xEaiyfUXtWh5DATORu1Oy5.xOI51wG_
 jLzLk1_8P1JlcvKIUpBnhn0Wy0.HKwJVeOrf3yrb.ZJtgeO7rK3xv06fucEu
 AccF2zdoQPhSJpGH7IH.XnqCy6o2j37AcF6Q3wTOt90O3fzZz9YOcQK6YsfP
 iEQk5uEx4sNgx92RIxXo7gXUzN_Mq9bXzq43PQs6PBfTHNbu8Zgvpg49IUcU
 F9DsZpUi0681tRW7YdwhhBAbG7KKSjpuQwyK.9pv1UEj9EV5BPzagf4nH9e
 0gNkuUhU6td01UREFWDZNl7Y5MQ84zP8PzolWb2iPgVggOtP1e5zxUx2m_x9
 m1BPPCQyaiYafL7UIpCcczPBjIHcYbxfsla6WMEfX7qGhwVHLKAAccx0zlv.
 nLL90efmyP6L_vRkllNkLGFX4SdYP6c9sgHW65rWFHvPgLAynDeJWRBemva0
 iro1HgBJZfLmBeZz1SyeLreupOZxYXgmziw3jCZvzGPq9qsQkvMN_5D3gEY9
 QaXjIMpoq1zXsO1L38NbrEyzeDTxKOE7aLj5tZjfeML0gw--
X-Originating-IP: [54.240.27.7]
Authentication-Results: mta1001.mail.ir2.yahoo.com  from=us-west-2.amazonses.com; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=us-west-2.amazonses.com; dkim=neutral (no sig)
Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO a27-7.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com) (54.240.27.7)
  by mta1001.mail.ir2.yahoo.com with SMTPS; Sun, 29 May 2016 14:58:53 +0000
From: MAILER-DAEMON@us-west-2.amazonses.com
To: balteo@yahoo.fr
Message-ID: <01010154fd06527b-89c9140b-c9d9-49ae-af67-ff99edb17d2c-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com>
Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/report; 
    boundary="----=_Part_1313673_1475756381.1464533930655"; 
    report-type=delivery-status
Date: Sun, 29 May 2016 14:58:50 +0000
X-SES-Outgoing: 2016.05.29-54.240.27.7
Content-Length: 1952
```

Can anyone please help?

**edit**:

Using linux and the sendemail command line utility, I get this:

```
May 30 15:04:02 beta sendemail[5004]: DEBUG => Connecting to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587
May 30 15:04:07 beta sendemail[5004]: DEBUG => My IP address is: 192.168.1.15
May 30 15:04:07 beta sendemail[5004]: SUCCESS => Received:  220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1463334051 hUc4mRbRHsRMfbM41cQq
May 30 15:04:07 beta sendemail[5004]: INFO => Sending:  EHLO beta
May 30 15:04:07 beta sendemail[5004]: SUCCESS => Received:  250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com, 250-8BITMIME, 250-SIZE 10485760, 250-STARTTLS, 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN, 250 Ok
May 30 15:04:07 beta sendemail[5004]: INFO => Sending:  STARTTLS
May 30 15:04:07 beta sendemail[5004]: SUCCESS => Received:  220 Ready to start TLS
May 30 15:04:07 beta sendemail[5004]: DEBUG => TLS session initialized :)
May 30 15:04:07 beta sendemail[5004]: INFO => Sending:  EHLO beta
May 30 15:04:07 beta sendemail[5004]: SUCCESS => Received:  250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com, 250-8BITMIME, 250-SIZE 10485760, 250-STARTTLS, 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN, 250 Ok
May 30 15:04:07 beta sendemail[5004]: DEBUG => SMTP-AUTH: Using LOGIN authentication method
May 30 15:04:07 beta sendemail[5004]: INFO => Sending:  AUTH LOGIN
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: SUCCESS => Received:  334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: INFO => Sending:  QUtJQUpMNlRZU0ZGNFdMM00zN1E=
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: SUCCESS => Received:  334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: INFO => Sending:  QW1zdkJ0WUMxaStFS2R2Z05Hcm1hVEw4T1RzTXdZTDdZRTZqNFU3QjJ5R0w=
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: SUCCESS => Received:  235 Authentication successful.
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: DEBUG => User authentication was successful (Method: LOGIN)
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: INFO => Sending:  MAIL FROM:<balteo@yahoo.fr>
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: SUCCESS => Received:  250 Ok
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: INFO => Sending:  RCPT TO:<balteo@gmail.com>
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: SUCCESS => Received:  250 Ok
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: INFO => Sending:  DATA
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: SUCCESS => Received:  354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: INFO => Sending message body
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: Setting content-type: text/plain
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: SUCCESS => Received:  250 Ok 0100015501c3abd4-f72c75e4-d159-48ad-aa8e-0ce1ff48493a-000000
May 30 15:04:08 beta sendemail[5004]: Email was sent successfully!  From: <balteo@yahoo.fr> To: <balteo@gmail.com> Subject: [Test] Server: [email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587]
```

... but the email is not delivered and comes back to the sender with the following message in email:

```
An error occurred while trying to deliver the mail to the following recipients:
balteo@gmail.comOK
```

**edit 2**: I have created an identity policy as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "stmt1464615598531",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::004523851570:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:004523851570:identity/balteo@yahoo.fr"
        }
    ]
}
```

I still can't send emails: same error message and email comes back to sender.

**edit 3**: All I have in the returned email body is the following:

```
----- Mail transféré -----

An error occurred while trying to deliver the mail to the following recipients:
balteo@gmail.comessai
```

Comment: I fixed a similar issue with AWS SES by using elevated IAM credentials (root credentials). Not sure why the SES credentials I created could not send, even thought they passed on the IAM simulator. Also consider switching SES to production enviroment. Until you do that, the enviroment is sandboxed, and that give you some headaches.

Comment: @Vini.g.fer: thanks for your comment. I was not able to find the way to elevate the credentials....

Comment: To send email through SES the IAM user must have the default AmazonSesSendingAccess policy attached the the user. This policy allows the ses:SendRawEmail action. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/control-user-access.html.  No other special privilege is required.

Comment: Was there a message body in the above email ?  I don't see one. It could contains something useful. like an error message or more details.

Comment: Yes I did have a body in the email.

Comment: I mean the body of of the error/returned email. That is not shown here I believe. All I see is the header section of the bounced email, not the message body. There may be more detail there. Can you provide that?

Comment: The headers in the above show Content-Length: 1952 but _you do not show_ that content. That will contain important information on why the email bounced.

Comment: Ah sorry. It it not the same email. The other email body just contained the original content i.e. the content meant to be delivered to the recipient.

Comment: Hm "balteo@gmail.comessai"?  Why is there an invalid email address there? That would cause an email to bounce in this exact way.

Comment: it is just a concatenation of the email and the text in the body. The recipient is balteo@gmail.com

Comment: I tried adding a custom policy with the content you provided. I get this: `Error while applying policy: Invalid ARN: ARNs must start with 'arn:': * (Request ID: dc9147bd-2670-11e6-989e-7f954b07da53)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113339/discussion-between-rodrigo-m-and-balteo).

Answer (score 1):

Try to troubleshoot all the basic settings first, using a tool like [SendEmail](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/)

The command will look like the following:

```
sendemail -v -t user@example.com -f user@example.com -u Test -m OK -s email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587 -xu [SMTP Username] -xp [SMTP Password]
```

The debug option -v will produce this type of output:

```
May 29 11:24:18 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: DEBUG => Connecting to email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587
May 29 11:24:20 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: DEBUG => My IP address is: 192.168.1.102
May 29 11:24:20 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: SUCCESS => Received:   220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1463334051 asd
May 29 11:24:20 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: INFO => Sending:       EHLO rodm-pc
May 29 11:24:20 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: SUCCESS => Received:   250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com, 250-8BITMIME, 250-SIZE 10485760, 250-STARTTLS, 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN, 250 Ok
May 29 11:24:20 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: INFO => Sending:       STARTTLS
May 29 11:24:20 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: SUCCESS => Received:   220 Ready to start TLS
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: DEBUG => TLS session initialized :)
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: INFO => Sending:       EHLO rodm-pc
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: SUCCESS => Received:   250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com, 250-8BITMIME, 250-SIZE 10485760, 250-STARTTLS, 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN, 250 Ok
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: DEBUG => SMTP-AUTH: Using LOGIN authentication method
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: INFO => Sending:       AUTH LOGIN
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: SUCCESS => Received:   334 asd
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: INFO => Sending:       asdfasdfasdf
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: SUCCESS => Received:   334 asd
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: INFO => Sending:       asdfasdfasfd
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: SUCCESS => Received:   235 Authentication successful.
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: DEBUG => User authentication was successful (Method: LOGIN)
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: INFO => Sending:       MAIL FROM:<user@example.com>
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: SUCCESS => Received:   250 Ok
May 29 11:24:22 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: INFO => Sending:       RCPT TO:<user@example.com>
May 29 11:24:23 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: SUCCESS => Received:   250 Ok
May 29 11:24:23 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: INFO => Sending:       DATA
May 29 11:24:23 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: SUCCESS => Received:   354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
May 29 11:24:23 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: INFO => Sending message body
May 29 11:24:23 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: Setting content-type: text/plain
May 29 11:24:23 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: SUCCESS => Received:   250 Ok 01000154fd54a817-33e6493f-e362-42d3-ae73-24839923c8ca-000000
May 29 11:24:23 rodm-pc sendemail[3660]: Email was sent successfully!  From: <user@example.com> To: <user@example.com> Subject: [test] Server: [email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587]
```

Work the options until you can send an email. Then go back and confirm the settings in your app.

Regarding the IAM policy, for troubleshooting purposes, try the default policy first:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ses:SendRawEmail",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Odd... I am using the command above i.e. `sendmail` on a mac and it just hangs indefinitely with no output...

Comment: The command I gave is SendEmail not sendmail.  Double check that.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and after some research it turned out the problem was that I was using a yahoo mail in the FROM field. It seems you can't send from yahoo. I see you are sending from ***@yahoo.fr

Switching it to a gmail solved the issue for me.